# remove git object directory?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I copied a few hundred megabytes of images from my production environment into my development environment. Even though I have them in `.gitignore` (`public/uploads/`) and they are not under version control (I checked with `git ls-tree -r master --name-only`) my last commit to GitHub was huge (a few hundred megabytes).

I saw that the few hundred megabytes seem to be in the following directory: `.git/objects/` in subfolders named from `00` to `ff`.
I can't see the `.git` directory on GitHub (where I commited to), but since there is the huge amount of data in it I guess it must be the reason for the commit > 100 MB. Can I simply delete the subfolders under `.git/objects` or how can I get rid of the hunderd MBs of images that I do not want to have under version control?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-do-i-purge-a-huge-file-from-commits-in-git-history

Comment: You should see the file in the history if it has been committed (try `gitk` or `gitx` for a user-friendly view). The `.git` directory doesn't show up on GitHub.

Comment: You could also type _git log --numstat_ on the command line to check wich files where affected by the last commit. Then you can decide what to do (ie. reset the commit or revert the commit).

Comment: The command `git ls-files` also lists all files tracked in the repository. Can you please describe how you committed and pushed files to GitHub since I suspect the problem there. Alternatively, you can post the address of the repository.

Comment: Did you git add, but then later add them to the ignore? It's possible you still have unreferenced objects floating around that'd get cleaned by a gc.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, git log --numstat and git ls-files are convenient! What I did was manually copy the images into the public/uploads folder (using Nautilus), since I also changed some code I also did a "git add ." and a git commit -am "Some changes". When I did "git push origin master" I saw that there are too many files. Anyhow, since I had public/uploads already in my gitignore I'm not sure why git bothered.